# Change Web Text Using PHP Based on URL Parameter

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to change the the article a/an in a webpage based on a parameter passed via the URL. So for example, I've got mywebpage.com/?page&qry=dog as the URL, so I would want any a/an articles to be "a" dog (vs "an" aardvark were that the qry). I'm trying to use the code below, however I'm getting a parse error any time I try to load the page.

```
<?php in_array(substr($_GET['qry'],0,1), array('a','e','i','o','u')) ? 'an' 'a'; ?>
```

If also tried an IF/ELSE statement, which lead to the same result.

```
<?php if(in_array(substr($_GET['qry'],0,1), array('a','e','i','o','u'))):'an':'a'; ?>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, most likely related to my attempt to insert this snippet amongst standard HTML text; can anyone spot my error(s)?

This is the error I get back:

> Parse error: parse error in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\testsite\html\page.html.php on line 117

Thank you!

Comment: `<?php if(in_array(substr($_GET['qry'],0,1), array('a','e','i','o','u')))?'an':'a'; ?>` try that. Not sure if it will work though.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: Parse error: parse error in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\testsite\html\page.html.php on line 117

Comment: Line 117 is the line where I have this code; if I remove it everything works fine.

Comment: `<?php in_array(substr($_GET['qry'],0,1), array('a','e','i','o','u'))?'an':'a'; ?>` removing the `if()`. Try that. Ternaries don't use `if`.

Comment: Perfect! Also, for anyone who tries to use this in the future, I'd forgotten to echo the statement (which is easily remedied...<?php echo ...

If you add the above as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as such. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I posted my answer below Jake, glad I could help, cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php in_array(substr($_GET['qry'],0,1), array('a','e','i','o','u')) ? 'an' : 'a'; ?>
```

Removing the `if()`. Ternary operators don't use `if()`, that's what they're for, to conditionally check all in one go.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

---

Footnotes: (OP)

> *"Perfect! Also, for anyone who tries to use this in the future, I'd forgotten to echo the statement (which is easily remedied...`<?php echo ...` If you add the above as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as such. Thank you so much for your help!"*

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator syntax is:

```
($conditions) ? "if condition is true" : "if condition is false";
```

In the first example you have a missing `:` between the possible values. And in the second you have an extra `:` after condition. Here is the manual and explanation for this operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (search for ternary operator)